# How can we remove a specific message from jboss mq using jboss cli

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, message-queue, mq, jboss-cli

I want to remove messages from jboss mq using certain filter , as I have googled the only filter available seems to be message-id 
I am looking to use other properties of message, ex. `JMSTimestamp`

I am looking for something like

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue="queuename"/:remove-message(timestamp>somevalue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the remove-messages operation that takes a filter as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the information
This is the syntax I used

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue="queuename"/: remove-messages(filter=JMSTimestamp > somevalue)
```